# Proving that:$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\int |f_n(x)|\log(1+ |f_n(x)|)dm=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory

Let $f_n(x)$ be a sequence in $L_2(X; m) $ such that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty }\| f_n\|_2=0 $$

To prove $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\int |f_n(x)|\log(1+ |f_n(x)|)dm=0$$ I want to use dominated convergence theorem, but it's hard to find a g such that  $$|f_n(x)|\log(1+ |f_n(x)|\leq g$$ for any n.

Answer (score 3):

well,  for all we have $x>0$ $$\log(x+1) =\int_0^x\frac{dt}{t+1}\le x$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\int |f_n(x)|\log(1+ |f_n(x)|)dm \le \lim_{n \to \infty }\int |f_n(x)|^2dm =\lim_{n \to \infty }\|f_n\|^2_2=0$$

Comment: yeah,I forget the $L_2$ property! thank you !

Comment: dont forget to put the green checkmark on the right corner it is important for upcomming users